# Is it obligatory for a mleccha householder to marry?

Tags: marriage, varna, mleccha

There are two options to most Hindus, householder or ascetic. Householders must get married. Is this law obligatory on foreigners as well? And what type of marriage would foreigners engage in? One of their own traditions?

Comment: I think so because they have to perform shraddha (ancestral rites) too.

Comment: Foreign converts to Hinduism have very few rules. I don't even think you have to worry about a marriage rite.

Comment: Inclination towards sexual intercourse or desire to have a family is human.  Hence, there will not be separate rules for Hindus and others. Ascetism doesn't mean becoming a monk or sanyasi, but doing Spiritual practice.  It can be done by a householder also. If one is got vexed mundane life and wants to be a monk, it is a different angle

Comment: Marriage is for sanctifying or legalising the proposed union of the couple. If it is marriage of Hindus, settled in abroad, then they are supposed to follow Hindu customs.     If it is marriage of other than Hindus, it is for them to decide.  it is done in Hindu or some other way, it doesn't matter.